# Why do I get internal error 500 when sending empty POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post

I develop API in Rails 4.0 and try to test it using Postman. I constantly get 500 status code as an answer for POST request with empty body.

It doesn't matter if I use correct url or not. It seems it's impossible to process empty POST request in rails. When I try it with PUT, DELETE and so on there is no problem.

Request:

```
POST /whatever HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c479c760-214d-93f0-3a49-2a11c95758f4
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Response headers:

```
Connection
Options that are desired for the connection
close
Content-Length
The length of the response body in octets (8-bit bytes)
296
Content-Type
The mime type of this content
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date → Fri, 22 May 2015 13:57:57 GMT
Server → WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)
```

Response body

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    bad content body
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26) at
     localhost:3000
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Server log:

```
[2015-05-22 16:12:57] ERROR EOFError: bad content body
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:96:in `block in fast_forward_to_first_boundary'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:94:in `loop'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:94:in `fast_forward_to_first_boundary'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:53:in `parse'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `parse_multipart'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/request.rb:373:in `parse_multipart'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/request.rb:207:in `POST'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:39:in `method_override_param'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:27:in `method_override'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /Users/fufu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Post your code that you are accessing from this POST request. It seems like you are expecting some values from the request but you are not getting it.

Comment: Check the rails server log after sending the request through CURL

Comment: I pasted it above, but it doesn't tell me anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well and it seems like `Postman` is sending an `empty body` when no POST parameters are defined. This trips up rails multipart parser because there is no `----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW boundary delimiter` that is supposed to surround the body of the request, hence the unexpected EOF. The solution is to switch to `x-www-form-urlencoded` (one of the 4 options under Body in Postman) instead.

Comment: WOW! This really tripped me up. Great catch, thank you.